# Gradient in IE9: using "filter: none" doesn't work

Tags: css, internet-explorer, cross-browser, internet-explorer-9

I've just generated a gradient using the [Colorzilla gradient editor](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/).

Using the rules generated it doesn't work for IE9, but I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8503431/should-i-use-the-svg-gradients-generated-by-colorzilla-for-ie9) and I expected it worked using a IE9 condition, but it still doesn't work..

```
<html>
<head>

<style type="text/css">
div {
background: rgb(208,228,247); /* Old browsers */
/* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiA/Pgo8c3ZnIHhtbG5zPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAwL3N2ZyIgd2lkdGg9IjEwMCUiIGhlaWdodD0iMTAwJSIgdmlld0JveD0iMCAwIDEgMSIgcHJlc2VydmVBc3BlY3RSYXRpbz0ibm9uZSI+CiAgPGxpbmVhckdyYWRpZW50IGlkPSJncmFkLXVjZ2ctZ2VuZXJhdGVkIiBncmFkaWVudFVuaXRzPSJ1c2VyU3BhY2VPblVzZSIgeDE9IjAlIiB5MT0iMCUiIHgyPSIwJSIgeTI9IjEwMCUiPgogICAgPHN0b3Agb2Zmc2V0PSIwJSIgc3RvcC1jb2xvcj0iI2QwZTRmNyIgc3RvcC1vcGFjaXR5PSIxIi8+CiAgICA8c3RvcCBvZmZzZXQ9IjUwJSIgc3RvcC1jb2xvcj0iIzBhNzdkNSIgc3RvcC1vcGFjaXR5PSIxIi8+CiAgICA8c3RvcCBvZmZzZXQ9IjEwMCUiIHN0b3AtY29sb3I9IiM4N2JjZWEiIHN0b3Atb3BhY2l0eT0iMSIvPgogIDwvbGluZWFyR3JhZGllbnQ+CiAgPHJlY3QgeD0iMCIgeT0iMCIgd2lkdGg9IjEiIGhlaWdodD0iMSIgZmlsbD0idXJsKCNncmFkLXVjZ2ctZ2VuZXJhdGVkKSIgLz4KPC9zdmc+);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(208,228,247,1) 0%, rgba(10,119,213,1) 50%, rgba(135,188,234,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(208,228,247,1)), color-stop(50%,rgba(10,119,213,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(135,188,234,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(208,228,247,1) 0%,rgba(10,119,213,1) 50%,rgba(135,188,234,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(208,228,247,1) 0%,rgba(10,119,213,1) 50%,rgba(135,188,234,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(208,228,247,1) 0%,rgba(10,119,213,1) 50%,rgba(135,188,234,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(top, rgba(208,228,247,1) 0%,rgba(10,119,213,1) 50%,rgba(135,188,234,1) 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#d0e4f7', endColorstr='#87bcea',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-8 */

}

</style>

<!--[if IE 9]>
  <style type="text/css">
    div {
       filter: none;
    }
  </style>
<![endif]-->

</head>
<body>


<div></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me (http://www.w3schools.com/svg/svg_grad_linear.asp)

/* IE 9 */

```
.some_element {
background-image: url(
header('Content-type: image/svg+xml; charset=utf-8');
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.0" preserveAspectRatio="none" width="100%" height="100%">
    <defs>
        <linearGradient id="linear-gradient" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="100%" spreadMethod="pad">
            <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#212121" stop-opacity="1"/>
            <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#cccccc" stop-opacity="1"/>
        </linearGradient>
    </defs>
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" style="fill: url(#linear-gradient);"/>
</svg>
);
}
```

You can update the values to what you want accordingly.  I did not use the filter:none CSS.

Answer (score 0):

It may not work because your document is in Quirks mode http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode#Triggering_different_rendering_modes.  I just spend a couple of hours trying all sorts of combinations of methods, none of which worked in IE9, then noticed the Debugging Tools window was telling me it was rendering in "Browser Mode: IE9  Document Mode: Quirks".  Putting `<!DOCTYPE html>` at the top of my document immediately fixed it.

It's a bit late to answer your question but I hope this will help others :)